# BitmapSource from file

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I load a `BitmapSource` from an image file?

Answer (score 57):

- [The `BitmapImage` class is a non-`abstract` subclass of `BitmapSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), so just use the `BitmapImage(Uri)` constructor and pass that new instance to anything that expects a `BitmapSource` object.
- Don't be confused by the fact the argument type is `System.Uri`: a `Uri` isn't just for `http://` addresses, but it's also suitable for local filesystem paths and UNC shares, and more.

So this works for me:

```
BitmapImage thisIsABitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("c:\\image.bmp"));

BitmapSource thisIsABitmapImageUpcastToBitmapSource = thisIsABitmapImage;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can read the bytes of the image from disk into a byte array and then create your BitmapImage object.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = stream;
img.EndInit();

return img;
```

Comment: But this leaks MemoryStream! You need to set CacheOption = OnLoad and dispose the stream afterwards.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no reason to ever dispose a MemoryStream, it's just a wrapper around a byte array and the dispose method on that class has an empty implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The code follows:

```
FileStream fileStream = 
    new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

var img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = fileStream;
img.EndInit();
```